# writing a simple string to a .txt file in python suddenly doesn't work

Tags: python, file, text

I have no idea why these lines of code stopped working all of a sudden.
I just restarted my kernel on jupyter notebook but for whatever reason it is not writing the string to the text file I'm specifying. My code is like this:

```
Code = 'H His\nQ Gln\nP Pro\nR Arg\nL Leu\nD Asp\nE Glu\nA Ala\nG Gly\nV Val\nY Tyr\n  STP\nS Ser\nC Cys\nW Trp\nF Phe\nN Asn\nK Lys\nT Thr\nS Ser\nI Ile\nM Met'
f=open('AA_Codon_code.txt','w+')
f.write(Code)
f.close
```

the text file all of a sudden doesn't have anything in it even though it shows up in my directory. There is no text in the text file.

Sure enough when I try to read the data it is empty.

```
data = open('AA_Codon_code.txt','r')
amino_acids = data.read()
peptide_dict = {}
amino_acids
```

I've used this method plenty of times but now it doesn't work. Why has this happened?

I just want a .txt file with this string written on it:

'H His\nQ Gln\nP Pro\nR Arg\nL Leu\nD Asp\nE Glu\nA Ala\nG Gly\nV Val\nY Tyr\n  STP\nS Ser\nC Cys\nW Trp\nF Phe\nN Asn\nK Lys\nT Thr\nS Ser\nI Ile\nM Met'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f.close` is just a name of a method. To call this method, you need parentheses:

```
f.close()
```

Comment: how embarrassing.Thank you so much